# Query All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Does anybody know how can I query All Subscribers ?

As we know _Subscribers data view keeps only records for 6 months, which means it is not a solution.

Currently I am trying to export All Subscribers and then import them into a Data Extension, but it would be nice if anybody knows different approach ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is none. Every data  view goes back to only 6 months. You'll need to contact Salesforce to give you a complete list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for the answer in SF documentation and contacting SF customer support we found out that I should query the data view _Subscribers like ent._Subscribers, usually the other data views we query them with no ent. at the front. But querying ent._Subscriber gave us the right result.
I recommend when trying to pull data from data view always to try to query both _Subscriber and ent._Subscribers.
Hope that will help somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

Only data views that hold specific events have a 6 month retention period, ie. Send, Open, Click, Unsubscribe, etc.

The _Subscribers data view is holding a reference of any subscriber in your account. There shouldn't be a 6 month retention period on this - feel free to run that query to test it out.

Comment: No, that's not true. I have tested that before and for example if you have 10m records in All Subscribers, when you query _Subscribers data view it gives me back just a small part of all, about 2m records.

Comment: Are you in an ET1.0 account with business units? If you sort by 'DateJoined' do you see records going back beyond 6 months?

Comment: Yeah, I see records going back beyond 6 months. The issue is solved, see the comment below. Thanks.